# SSMS login fail to Linked Server

Tags: sql-server-2012, ssms, connections

i have one server with SQL server 2012 standard on cloud environment and one linked server with sql express on remote location connected with VPN , im using transactional replication

every time when internet conection is dropped and regain on remote location, i try to connect with SSMS im getting error

> "A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - The specified network
>   name is no longer available.) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 64)
>
> For help, click:
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=64&LinkId=20476
>
> The specified network name is no longer available"

But when i test the connection in server object/linked server, the connection is ok and the replication is running

one resolution was to restart the cloud server and everything is normal i can connect to remote server via ssms, but this is no resolution for me

can somebody help me with this one

Comment: Sounds like the same message you get when you attempt to continue using an open session against a server that has been restarted.  If this is the case, refreshing the server in Object explorer and creating a new connection should avoid the error.